# get the table row cell value

Tags: jquery

I am using the HTML table. the first column contain the checkbox. How to get the cell values of the checked row using jquery.

Thanks,
Nizam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#myTable input:checked').parent('tr').find('td')
```

You can then get the contents of the cells using `.html()` or `.text()` or whatever you want depending on exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to get a table cell value using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)