# possible to generate summaries/statistics from html table?

Tags: html

If I have a table like:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| PRIORITY  | ITEM      | COMPLETED |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    0      | foo       |    YES    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1      | bar       |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    2      | baz       |    YES    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Can plain ol' HTML auto-generate a final summary line like:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |   2/3     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: The `M` of `HTML` stands for **Markup**, not for **Programming**. Use a real programming or scripting language to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It can't. HTML can't iterate over the rows. With JavaScript it's no problem.

fn. [How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible using Javascript or server-side code.