# Get Row data using jquery

Tags: jquery

I implement some thing like this

```
- person grid -
name        address     action
a           ax          edit
b           bx          edit

- form edit -
id         :
name       :
address    :
<submit edit>
```

action edit is a link, supposed the anchor tag is: `<a href="http://localhost/person/edit/1">`
while I click the edit link. the personf information will displayed in id, name, address text filed.
supposed, the input filed name. `txt_id, txt_name, txt_address`.

my implementation is:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    $.parrent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.id = ... //get id
    $.name = ...//get name
    $.address = ...//get address

    ${"txt_id"}.val($.id);
    ${"txt_address"}.val($.address);
    ${"txt_name"}.val($.name);
    return false;
});
```

I dont know how to implement get id, get name, get address after I get the parrent.
Is there any suggestion ? or Is there any other sollution ?

```
Edit
```

And while click submit edit, I will display the new name and address to the current edited row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var $td      = $(this).closest('tr').children('td'),
        $id      = parseInt($(this).attr('href').replace('http://localhost/person/edit/',''), 10),
        $name    = $td.eq(0).text(),
        $address = $td.eq(1).text();

    $("#txt_id").val($id);
    $("#txt_address").val($address);
    $("#txt_name").val($name);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it's work perfectly. but, there some problem occurred. While I sumbit the edited person, I want the current row update. do you have any suggestion to implement my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery td:nth-child(n) to get the value from each td cell.  See a similar question [How to get a table cell value using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)