# Find nested DOM elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, nested, element

I need to find specific elements in my DOM using JQuery.

The case is:

```
var dialog = $(DOM.loadHTML("amc-refine", "scripts/dialogs/amc-dialog.html"));
elmts = DOM.bind(dialog);
```

So elmts here is a variable with the DOM elements ..
i have a table that i can access it using

```
$(elmts.dialogTable)
```

using jQuery i would like to reach nested elements inside this table .. for example i want to do the following

```
$('#example thead tr').each( function () {
        this.insertBefore( nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0] );
    } );
```

but i cant access my table using the # .. so can i do this:

```
$(elmts.dialogTable).find('thead').find('tr')
```

moreover, what if i want to reach also

```
$('#example tbody td img')
```

using the same $(elmts.dialogTable)

Best Regards

Comment: You can search inside the loaded dom, like `$("thead tr",elmts.dialogTable)` - but im not quite sure whats inside your DOM... Could you paste the content of amc-dialog.html?

Comment: I think the link below is related to your query:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to still use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and pass the entire selector to it:

```
var img = $(elmts.dialogTable).find('tbody td img');
```

You don't need to call `find` multiple times as you have done in your example. Your example could be rewritten to just use `find('thead tr')`.

Alternatively, you could use `elmts.dialogTable` as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) in which to select:

```
var img = $("tbody td img", elmts.dialogTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible:

```
$('#example thead tr', elmts.dialogTable).each( function () {
        this.insertBefore( nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0] );
    } );
```

The second parameter means `context`.