# Really basic jQuery: how can I check to see if a table cell has a value?

Tags: jquery, html

Been Googling this for over an hour, and getting answers to much more complex questions but not this simple one, and my Dummies book is no help.

I want to change the background of a row if a particular cell has a value. So:

```
$('#MyTable tr').each (function(index) {

    $(this).css('background-color', '#FCDCE4');

});
```

Works fine to change the bg color in every row, but how can I do this only in rows where column 30 has a value? I could probably give my target cell a css class and do it that way, but I'd really rather learn to use jQuery properly (so that I don't need to keep posting elementary questions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a table cell value using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

Comment: As a general point: have you tried just reading the official documentation, rather than trying to google this?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuery `.children()` and `.eq()` to get the cell 30.

**Note that .eq() is zero based, so you need to use 29 to get the 30th cell**

#### Sample

```
$('#MyTable tr)').each (function(index) {
    var cell = $(this).children("td").eq(29)

    // your if condition

    $(this).css('background-color', '#FCDCE4');
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [jQuery - children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Thank you, and I'll look at those links that you supplied - although some of that documentation is still a bit above me, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table td:nth-child(30):empty').each(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','#FCDCE4'); // empty column
});
```

[`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to grab the 30th column
[`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) to grab empty cells.

Example on jsFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pYA4U/

Comment: The OP wants to change the background-color of the row, not the cell itself.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Use `$(this).closest('tr').css(...)` then.

Comment: `$( this ).parent()` is fine too.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I ran across that 'nth child' syntax while I was looking, but I didn't think it was what I wanted. I'll go back and read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

First, put the reference to the table inside a variable:

```
var table = $( '#myTable' )[0];
```

You probably want to keep this reference available throughout your application (so that all your methods have access to it).

Next:

```
var nr = 30; // the column number

$( table.rows ).each( function () {    
    if ( $( this.cells ).eq( nr - 1 ).text() ) {
        $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );
    }
});
```

So, if the 30. cell has any text-content, add the `'selected'` class to the row.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2C6C7/