# I'm trying to get the value of a 'td' using jQuery, but it always reports 'null'

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the value of a specific cell in a table in order to filter out unwanted rows. However, when I try to get the value of that cell it always reports `null` or nothing at all. I've looked at several sources and done my code the same way with no luck. Here is my code:

```
$("td").each(function () {
    var setName = $(this).find("#headerName").text();
    alert(setName);
    if (setName != weaverSet) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
```

`weaverSet` is getting it's value passed from the drop down and working correctly. Here is the code for the part of the table I am trying to get:

```
 <td id ="headerName">
     @item.WeaverSetName
 </td>
```

Any help is appreciated on this issue.

Comment: You are already iterating over all cells. No cell contains another cell with ID `headerName`, *one of the cells itself* has that ID.  You can get the content of the element with the ID with `$('#headerName').text()`. You can get each cell's content with `$(this).text()`. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, a simple and complete example at http://jsfiddle.net/ would be helpful.

Comment: This may answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery

Comment: @Felix Kling That comments should be the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `filter("#headerName")` instead of `find("#headerName")`

You are already iterating over all cells. `find` looks for a cell with and id `headerName` inside each cell. What you probably wanted is to check if current cell has an id which is done using `filter()` function.

Comment: That would result in another then, because `.is` returns a boolean and not a jQuery object (and calling `.text` on the return value would fail).

Comment: Thanks, the filter gets the value that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value of the td without calling the find function. Inside your loop get the value like this

```
var setName = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you should most likely be using a class for headerName as opposed to an ID (which there should only be one of on your page).

You could then perform your same iteration.

```
$("td").each(function () {
     var setName = $('.headerName',this).text();
     alert(setName);
     if (setName != weaverSet) {$(this).hide();}
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLvmd/1/)**

or as they are just  elements, you should be able to pull the text from them completely, along with their contents:

```
$("td").each(function()
{
     var setName = $(this).text();
     alert(setName);
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLvmd/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there would only work if the #headerName cell were inside yet another `<td>`.  Is there just one `<td>` with the ID headerName?  If so, this should work (without the .each() around it):

```
var cell= $("#headerName");
var setName = cell.text();
            alert(setName);
            if (setName != weaverSet) {
                $(cell).hide();
            }
```

If not, then that's problematic, because IDs need to be unique, and you should be using classes in that case.