# Find the value of a datatable cell

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

how to get the value of a datatable cell. I was trying the following code to get the value but its not working. Can anyone help

```
             $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#edit_table").dataTable().makeEditable({
            var id = aData[2],
            sUpdateURL: "/submitchanges/"+id,
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                {

                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: There is no such .dataTable() event or makeEditable() event.  You probably want to use ajax for this, `$.ajax` or `.load()` event.

Comment: can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do exactly?  Just grab the value of a cell from the database?  You will need to use php to do this, jQuery doesn't query the database, it's not able to, it's a client-side script, not server-side.  Use `.load("{path to your php file}, {variables});`

Comment: Or jQuery.get():  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or jQuery.post():  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  Those links provide examples of how you should do it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a table from jQuery you can use a bunch of features that allows you to navigate the table.

A question similar was answered in an excellent way here in StackOverflow: [How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

Comment: So one more thing ...i got the value from $('#edit_table tr').each(function()    and now i need to get the same value in document.ready function/.how ?

Comment: Sorry just, I don't understand your question. You want it on page load let's say? I suggest reading the .ready() jQuery manual page http://api.jquery.com/ready/