# How to edit values of GridView with AutoGenerateColumns="true" in C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple `Gridview` with `AutoGeneratecolumns=true`, which binds data from different tables on each execution as per requirement. There are different number of columns on each table,that's why i'm not using "`asp:TemplateField`" or "`asp:BoundField`".

Is there any way to edit `GridView` columns?

Answer (score 0):

Gridview  has property `AutoGenerateDeleteButton` and `AutoGenerateEditButton` you can set to true. Try using that

Comment: in AutoGenerateEditButton="true" we have to specify asp:EditTemplateField or asp:BoundField but in my case we don't know numbers of return column thats why use AutoGeneratecolumns=true. is there any alternative?

Comment: @ManishMishra: Well If you bind your gridview using datatable you can get the count of column, so loop over it you can add boundfield

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutogenerateEditbutton` property to automatically generate edit button Or u can add a button manually and edit the gridview.

Comment: in AutoGenerateEditButton="true" we have to specify asp:EditTemplateField or asp:BoundField but in my case we don't know numbers of return column thats why use AutoGeneratecolumns=true. is there any alternative?

Comment: @ManishMishra s in templatefield add edit button or set autogenerateEditbutton property to true and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

as asp.net gridview rendered to a html table in the browser I think you can use Jquery to select every cell of each from the table and then update:

[get a table cell value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)