# find value of a particaular cell in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is ther any way to find the value of a datatable cell. I know the rowId and coloumnID and i need to get the value of that cell. How i can do with jquery. i was trying the following code. but it is not working. Can anyone help.

```
       var maint_id;
            maint_id = $('#edit_table tr').find("td:eq(0)").html;
```

SO Basically what i am looking is the value of the cell rowID-0 and ColoumnID 0. i know only the position of the cell. The value may change on each iteration. ANy help

Comment: Even if the selector is correct, you need `html()` (with braces) to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
var celvalue = $('#edit_table tr:eq(rowindex) td:eq(cellindex)').html()
```

see this similar question:

[How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)