# Get Columns Name or Header Text of GridView Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am developing a web application where I need Column's name of grid view using javascript. After that, display this column's name on Div.

Please help me out this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to do so. GridView is nothing but a html table at runtime. So best you can do is to grab this table through javascript and grab its columns.

Suppose, you have declared your `gridview` like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

and have bound it at runtime like this:

```
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        db.Columns.Add("Col1");
        db.Columns.Add("Col2");

        db.Rows.Add("one", "two");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

then at runtime, a markup like below is generated for your `gridView`

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" 
       style="border-collapse:collapse;">
     <tr>
         <th scope="col">Col1</th>
         <th scope="col">Col2</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

so clearly, columns are the `th` elements in the `GridView` table, which you can easily grab through javascript like below:

```
var table = document.getElementById('GridView1');
var headers = table.getElementsByTagName('th');

for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++)
{
    alert(headers[i].innerText);
    //or append to some div innerText
}
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he7HA/) on how to grab table elements

Comment: Hello Manish Mishra,Thanks

Comment: Hey Manish, i passing my GridId its not giving my ID             var table = document.getElementById('<%= grd.ClientID %>');
            alert(table);

Comment: hi Manish Mishra. can i bind this header with checklist box i m doing that but its not working...

Answer (score 0):

GridView is rendered as HTML table on your page source, hence you can use Jquery to get the , view source and check if its associated with any class and then you can use it as selector, or regular `$('table tr th')` this post may help you [How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

Comment: Hello Vishal Sachdeva, thanks but i don't want jquery i want use only javascript

Comment: I dont think there is any difference is both of them Jquery is a library developed using JS to help you reduce syntax, nothing more so document.getElementById('ID') is wripped to $('#ID').