# Copy contents of one field to another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table structure like:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
              <th class='name'>Name</th>
              <th class='nick-name'>Nick Name</th>
              <th class='age'>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Ilona</td>
              <td class='nick-name'>Baby Doll</td>
              <td class='age'>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Sieraa</td>
              <td class='nick-name'></td>
              <td class='age'>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Britney</td>
              <td class='nick-name'>Blondie</td>
              <td class='age'>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Kate</td>
              <td class='nick-name'>Night Queen</td>
              <td class='age'>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Dani</td>
              <td class='nick-name'></td>
              <td class='age'>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Aliee</td>
              <td class='nick-name'></td>
              <td class='age'>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class='name'>Brandi</td>
              <td class='nick-name'></td>
              <td class='age'>27</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As some **Nick Name** fields are empty, I want to display the value of **Name** in **Nick Name** if they are empty.

Eg: In **Second Row** of Table Body, The ***Nick Name*** field is empty, The ***Name*** field contains **Sierra**. So, I want to display **Sierra** in ***Nick Name*** field instead of leaving it empty.

How can I achieve this using **jQuery** or **JavaScript**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery:

this only works when the .name is always the exact previous element of .nick-name like in your structure

```
$('.nick-name').each(function () {
 if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
   $(this).text($(this).prev().text());
 }
});
```

This works when both .name and .nick-name have the same parent

```
$('.nick-name').each(function () {
 if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
   var name = $(this).parent().find('.name').text();
   $(this).text(name);
 }
});
```

You should read up on [DOM Traversing with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), there is lots of stuff you can do to get to your elements.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sX4yj/

Comment: This is nice, if you could give me example of using _class name_ instead of `prev()` then it'd be more helpful in my case. I tried `$(this).text($('.name').text());` instead of `$(this).text($(this).prev().text());` but it displays all the value. I am still n00b.

Comment: updated answer. and being a n00b at something is the first step to actually get good at something, so keep on doing stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function(){

        var nickname = $(this).find('.nick-name').html();
        alert(nickname);

});
```

Refer: [How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)