# Setting CGridview selected row column value in form text field - YII Framework

Tags: yii, cgridview

How to set the grid's selected column value in lookup field as shown in image?

[image]

My view code,

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'dataProvider' => AgentsModel::model()->search(),//searchByLogin(AgentsModel::model()->g_user_id),
                'id' => 'CGridViewUser',
            'selectionChanged'=>'
            function(id){
          id=$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);
          alert(id);
        }',

                'columns' => array(
                    'g_user_id',
                    'name',
                    'lastname',
                    'phone',
                    'mobile',
                  'email',
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'style'=>'cursor: pointer;',
                    ),                   

            ));
```

from above code im getting selected rowid,but dont know how to proceed further!!!

Comment: what is your exact need? Need to set data in textboxes when selecting row or doing search?

Comment: yes,have to set grid column "Name" value in textbox...

Comment: Are you using advanced search option? It will work when you are doing search with ajax.

Comment: No,here no search involved...just selecting the grid row should update the textbox with the value of grid column 'Name' that's all

Comment: Then you have to do with jquery with onclick event. In first answer, you just said "Yes" for both option. "Yes" for what?

Comment: on selecting row set value in textbox,can you give somw example code to get grid column value and setting in textfield?

Comment: check this SO url for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery

Comment: this is for table ,but i need it for cgridview can you provide some other extra informations to likw, 1) get particular column value from grid 2)setting that value in form textfield

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, You have to assign some class name to each fields like `cell1, cell2, cell3..etc`.

Then try something like below:

```
$(".cell1").live("click",function(){

    $(".cell1_txt").val($(this).html());// cell1_txt is text class name. 

});
```

So each row can have class like `cell1` for first cell, `cell2` for 2ed cell .. etc.,

but textboxes must have class like `cell1_txt`, `cell2_txt`, `cell3_txt`.. etc.,

Comment: how to specify particular form's textfield?

Comment: each form field having separate class name.clearly mentioned in my answer.