# targeting an element by its content and the content of its ancestors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [<kbd>This Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/r55jtgub/) and let me know how I can add the `.today` class to the `<td>` which has value of `day` and the parent has value of the `month`.

```
var month = "October";
var day = 16;
```

I already tried with `.find()` as:

```
$("thead tr").find("th").html(month).addClass('today');
```

but this just adding the month to all of the `thead tr`

Comment: A possible solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery Use this to find the value of a cell then compare against day and set class for that cell. Putting IDs on elements could make life easier.

Comment: for a one line solution, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:contains` this way:

```
$("table:contains(" + month + ")")
   .find("td:contains(" + day + ")")
   .addClass('today');
```

---

```js
var month = "October";
var day = 16;

$("table:contains(" + month + ")").find("td:contains(" + day + ")").addClass('today');
```

```css
table {
  background: grey;
}
.today {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Feburary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table style="width:50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">October</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table style="width:50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">March</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table style="width:50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">May</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that `:contains` searches for all elements that *contain* the searched string. So, searching for `1`, will highlight `15`, `16`, `17`, `18`.

You can fix this by using `filter()` method:

```
$("table:contains(" + month + ")")
   .find("td").filter(function () {
       return $(this).text() === day.toString()
   })
   .addClass('today');
```

Comment: Hi Ionică, thanks for comment and your logic on using is 100% correct but I do not know it is not working on my demo at here : http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/0w9rkp49/

Comment: @Suffii Good catch, `return` was missing inside of `filter` callback. See [update fidlde](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9rkp49/3/) and updated answer. Thanks for pinging. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Like This:

```
$("th:contains("+month+")").parents("table").find("td:contains("+day+")").addClass("today");
```

we find the `<th>` that contains the month, get the table it belongs to, and then search for the `<td>` that contains the date.

<kbd>**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/r55jtgub/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Banana, but Inoica is right about the last note he added tho his comment,

Comment: yep he absolutely is :)

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you have to use the "**:contains()**" and "**filter()**" selectors.

Using "**filter()**" will let you explicitly check a string to see if it is exactly the same as your search term as opposed to allowing all strings that contain the search term to be returned.

```
$("table:contains(" + month + ")").find("td").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === day.toString()
}).addClass('today');
```

This function will look for a table that contains the value of "**month**", then it will query that table for a "**td**" selector that explicitly contains the value of "**day**" so it can add the class "today" to it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/o0110o/cygzgfzj/2/

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/filter/