# HTML Table - Iterate over row and sum the fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, html-table

I have then following table:

```
    <table style="width:100%" id="testTable">
    <tr>
        <th>length per</th>
        <th>width per</th> 
        <th>length</th>
        <th>width</th>
        <th>total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align='right'>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="length-per-input">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="width-per-input">
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="length-total-input">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="width-total-input">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="total-output" disabled="disabled">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align='right'>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="length-per-input">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="width-per-input">
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="length-total-input">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="width-total-input">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="total-output" disabled="disabled">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type=button value='+' onclick="addRow()" />
<input type=button value='Calculate' onclick="Calculate()" />
```

I also have the javascript which adds the value and puts it in total:

```
<script>
    function Calculate() {
        var lengthPerInput = $("input[name='length-per-input']").val();
        var widthPerInput = $("input[name='width-per-input']").val();
        var lengthTotal = $("input[name='length-total-input']").val();
        var widthTotal = $("input[name='width-total-input']").val();
        var total = (lengthTotal/lengthPerInput) + (widthTotal/widthPerInput);
        $("input[name='total-output']").val(total);
    }
</script>
```

The aim here is to have it iterate over the two rows, then add each one separately.
I know how to get each row by using:

```
$('#testTable tr').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
    $(this).find('length-per-input').each(function(){
        console.log(this);
    })
})
```

But using the row (accessed via "this") I don't know how to get the correct cells, get their value, then perform the calculate on that row for the total.

Any advice on this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function Calculate(tr_row) {
        var lengthPerInput = tr_row.find("input[name='length-per-input']").val();
        var widthPerInput = tr_row.find("input[name='width-per-input']").val();
        var lengthTotal = tr_row.find("input[name='length-total-input']").val();
        var widthTotal = tr_row.find("input[name='width-total-input']").val();
        var total = (lengthTotal/lengthPerInput) + (widthTotal/widthPerInput);
        tr_row.find("input[name='total-output']").val(total);
    }
```

For every row you call function to summ the values
To the function you pass the row, then it can collect values on that row

```
$('#testTable tr').each(function(){
    Calculate($(this))   
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks, appreciate the quick and brilliant responses!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to iterate through `table` and use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function to find `cell` values.

```
function Calculate() {
  $('#testTable tr').each(function() {
    var lengthPerInput = $(this).find("input[name='length-per-input']").val();
    var widthPerInput = $(this).find("input[name='width-per-input']").val();
    var lengthTotal = $(this).find("input[name='length-total-input']").val();
    var widthTotal = $(this).find("input[name='width-total-input']").val();
    var total = (lengthTotal/lengthPerInput) + (widthTotal/widthPerInput);
    $(this).find("input[name='total-output']").val(total);
  });
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9eeNrA7wqXCEcoRVGf6Z?p=preview)

[How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)