# How to set default color based on a column condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="Center" border="0" id="ctl00_centerContent_GridView1" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
            <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #1</a></td>
            <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
            <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #2</a></td>
            <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">N</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
            <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #3</a></td>
            <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
            <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #4</a></td>
            <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">Y</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am setting the Url, the color, and the cursor through a JQuery:

```
$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a").each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');
    if (cid == "34" || cid == "37") {
        $(this)
            .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);')
            .css({ color: 'black', cursor: 'default' });
    }
});
```

How can I modify the code so if the query string is `34` or `37` and if the third column is a Y make the font color red instead of black otherwise make the font color red. Leave everything else in the code as is.

Comment: This question is so unclear. Do you mean to say if cid is 34 or 37, then for each row where the third column contains a value of Y, set the font color to red. Otherwise, leave it black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Add a class to each `<td>` who has the Y/N value like this:**

```
 <td align="center" class="yes_no">Y</td>
```

**2. Update your `each` to look at sibling `.yes_no` text like this:**

```
$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a").each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');
    var yes_no_value = $(this).parent('td').siblings('.yes_no').text();
    if (cid == "34" || cid == "37") {
        var new_color = (yes_no_value == 'N') ? 'red' : 'black';
        $(this)
            .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);')
            .css({ color: new_color, cursor: 'default' });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Although most of them can work, this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the third column like this:-

```
 var url = $(this).attr("href");
 var cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');
 var parentrow = $(this).parents('tr')[0]; //find the parent tr
 var thirdColumn = $('td:nth-child(3)', parentrow); //find 3rd td in that tr
```

Then, simply apply the condition:-

```
if (cid == "34" || cid == "37") {
     if (thirdColumn.text() == "Y")
          $(this).css({ color: 'red', cursor: 'default' });
     else
          $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);')
                 .css({ color: 'black', cursor: 'default' });
}
```

Comment: @SiKni8 - You're Welcome :) Can you tell me if you faced any issue while running my code? Cz it didn't need any class to be added.

Comment: Actually your code works fine also but I went with the class option because of other things that I needed to do. I +1 your solution because it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a class on the cell when it's a Y, and then find by that class as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery).

Just add something like this in your codebehind for the row (pseudo-code):

```
if (cell.Value == "Y")
{
cell.CssClass="something"
}
```

Then you can pick up the class with jQuery's `$(".something")` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (So while I was typing this the above answerer suggested this already) If I'm understanding this correctly you could simply add a class to the `<td>`'s that will have a 'Y' for content and instead of targeting `$(this)` use `$(this.new_class)` (or how ever you select that) and apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to differentiate `Y/N` `td` from other `td` elements. In this example I have used `.YN` class to distinguish

```js
var getParameterByName = function(url, name) {
  if (!url) url = location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
};


$("#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a").each(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  var cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');
  if ((cid == "34" || cid == "37") && $(this).parents('tr').find('.YN').text() === 'Y') {
    $(this)
      .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);')
      .css({
        color: 'red',
        cursor: 'default'
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="Center" border="0" id="ctl00_centerContent_GridView1" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #1</a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" class="YN">N</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #2</a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" class="YN">N</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #3</a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" class="YN">Y</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="http://localhost/SO/index.html?ccid=37" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #4</a>
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" class="YN">Y</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather see this done with css (not writing styles directly as html attributes), but here you go:

```
$('#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
        cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');

    if (cid == '34' || cid == '37') {
        var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');

        if ($parent.children('td:nth-child(3)').text() === 'Y') {
            var $children = $parent.children('td');

            $children
                .css({ 'color': 'red' })
                .find('a').css({ 'color': 'red' });
        }
    }
});
```

Feel free to condense the code. I've assigned variables so you can easily tell what's happening.

```js
'use strict';

var cid = '34';

$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('#ctl00_centerContent_GridView1 tr td a').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); //,
    //cid = getParameterByName(url, 'ccid');

    if (cid == '34' || cid == '37') {
      var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');

      if ($parent.children('td:nth-child(3)').text() === 'Y') {
        var $children = $parent.children('td');

        $children.css({
            'color': 'red'
          })
          .find('a').css({
            'color': 'red'
          });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="Center" border="0" id="ctl00_centerContent_GridView1" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #1</a>

      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center">N</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #2</a>

      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center">N</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #3</a>

      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center">Y</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:SeaShell;">
      <td class="nonpar" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: black; cursor: default;">Entry #4</a>

      </td>
      <td align="center" style="color:Red;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center">Y</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```