# How do I just get the cell values of the rows from a column (and not the header) of the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I just want to get the cell values from the rows of a column, but I do no want to get the undefined at the start. 
I think this undefined is the is the undefined `td` in the first `tr` of the table.

How do I just get the cell values of the rows from a column (and not the header) of the table?

my current [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/poep7xee/) gets me this in the the console:

undefined
123
456
789

or

undefined
abc
def
ghi

so the answer I would expect is

123
456
789

or

abc
def
ghi

**Note** Similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery/376095#376095) which has helped get to this point

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude the first header row with `#mytable tr:not(:first)` selector:

```
$('#mytable tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
    console.log(customerId)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple check would solve it:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("td").eq(0).length) {
    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
    console.log(customerId)
  }
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/cLv9gk08/**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poep7xee/1/)

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find("td:first").html();    
});


//OPTION 2 
//To select a particular cell, you can reference them with an index:
$('#mytable tr').each(function(index) {
if(index !== 0){
   var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();    
    console.log(customerId);
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to put the header row into a `<thead>` section and all the rows into a `<tbody>` so you can then use `$('#mytable tbody tr').each(.....);` which will automatically exclude the header.

Comment: tks, good idea, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/poep7xee/2/)

Answer (score -1):

var customerId = $(this).find("td").html();