# Finding a certain number in html and replace it with custom text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a table and there is a colum called value with different numbers that varies from 0 to 2.

```
<column>Values<column>
<td>0</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>0</td>
```

Yes, I know that something like  does not exist, it was just for sake of example. 
But the real question is, how can I with help of jquery find those numbers and replace it with something else.. for example

```
    if(td == 1){
       replace 1 with "Hello"
    }
```

Comment: `$('td').text(function(i,v){ return v=='1' ? 'hello' : v; });`

Comment: `$('td:contains(1)').text(function(i,v){ return v == '1' ? 'hello' : v; });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains()` to get td which have similar text and replace text using `.text()`

```js
$("td:contains('1')").text("hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was experimenting IsNumeric to find out if it is number and then trying to replace it with html text, but it did not worked at some point so ended up asking here

Comment: @Harugawa : it will replace text if content is `11`

Answer (score 0):

Can you give your elements Id's? This may make your code more readable and maintainable, and will remove the dependency between the value you are trying to replace and the code that is looking for it.

If you can use Id's, then you can use [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get hold of the element and then, depending on the element type, set the `text` or `innerHtml` to your required values.

Foe example;

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#col1').text('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="col1">1</td>
    <td id="col2">2</td>
    <td id="col3">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or [JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/liquidjelly/zh10grr9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends...

If you are refering to ALL the content of the cell as a numeric value, you can do this (in JS)

```
if(Number($(td).html().trim()) == number_to_replace){
    $(td).html(text_for_replacement);
}
```

where "td" could referer to the cell as a DOM variable or could be a string selector

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** pseudo-class to select all td which contains `1` and then use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** with callback to check content is exactly `1` and update.

```js
$('td:contains(1)').text(function(i, v) {
  return $.trim(v) == '1' ? 'hello' : v;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```