# Get Value from a specific cell in a specific column using jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose I have this table:

```
<table id="mytable" border="1">
<tr id="element">
  <td>value1</td>
  <td>text1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="element">
  <td>value2</td>
  <td>text2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get get the value "text2". What I have so far is this:

```
var _value = $('#mytable tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').val();
alert(_value);
```

My alert says "undefined"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. Keep in mind ids must be unique so #element should be a class if you're going to use it.

Also there is no "value" assigned to that table cell. So `.val()` won't work. You can use `.text()` instead.

You're also trying to use `.eq()` in the selector when it is it's on method. So you need to choose the selector or your starting point and then chain the `.eq()` to select the element you need.

```
var _value = $('#mytable td').eq(3).text();
alert(_value);
```

#### Demo

```js
var _value = $('#mytable td').eq(3).text();
alert(_value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr id="element">
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="element">
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question are similar to another that you cant find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

But i think that in your case must to be more similar with something like this:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();    
    console.log(_value);
});
```

Comment: This is quite good but it goes through all the cells in the column. I just need 1.