# Return value of specific table element through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table  id="table1" width="300" border="2" align="right" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
          <tr class="tb1">
          <td>station</td>
          <td>wind</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope to return the value of  element through javascript
which I expect to alert with the string "station" and "wind".
I had tried the following javascript code

```
var data=$("tr.tb1").find("td").value;
alert(data);
```

And further more to change the font color of the content.
Hoping to get some help about how to improve my code.

Comment: Might be similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/376081/7124761

Comment: `td`s don't have `value`, they have `textContent` and `innerHTML`. Notice, that `find` returns a jQuery object, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

You can use `each()` to get all `td`'s returned by `.find()`. There is no `value` attribute in `td`, you can use `textContent` instead.
Try the following:

```js
$(".tb1").find("td").each(function(){ 
  var data = this.textContent;
  alert(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table  id="table1" width="300" border="2" align="right" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
          <tr class="tb1">
            <td>station</td>
            <td>wind</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.text()` to get the text content of a dom element

`.val()` works on input elements and `.text()` will not work on input elements.
more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text)

```js
var data=$("tr.tb1").find("td").text();
alert(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table  id="table1" width="300" border="2" align="right" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
          <tr class="tb1">
          <td>station</td>
          <td>wind</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.tb1').find("td").each(function()
{
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call): [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Code:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('tr.tb1 td');
const result = Array.prototype.map.call(elems, el => el.innerHTML).join(' ');

alert(result);
```

```html
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table  id="table1" width="300" border="2" align="right" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
          <tr class="tb1">
            <td>station</td>
            <td>wind</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery text method `.text();` or `.html()` like this:

```
var data=$("#table1 .tb1").find("td");

alert(data.html());
alert(data.text());
```

And for css styling

```
data.css({"color": "blue"});
```